# Implementing PasswordDeriveBytes in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, encryption, sha1

I am trying to read some encrypted data in Silverlight, which was encrypted using a legacy .NET application using `PasswordDeriveBytes` to generate the key. I'm aware that we are supposed to use `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` nowadays, but the existing application is deployed in 2000+ locations and changing the encryption of the data in all those places just to implement a Silverlight version of the UI won't be feasible at this time.

I've tried implementing my own version of `PasswordDeriveBytes.GetBytes(int byteCount)`, but while I can easily get the first 20 bytes (using SHA1 hashing), I can't figure out how the next set of bytes is calculated (I need to generate a 32 byte password). According to what I've read, Microsoft is using an "extension" of PBKDF1 to calculate the key, but I haven't found any information on what that extension might be.

I have tried porting code from the Mono project's implementation of `PasswordDeriveBytes`, and code I found in a few other places on the Web, but they all return a completely different password than the original .NET class (even for the first 20 bytes).

This is a version of `GetBytes()` that returns the correct first 20 bytes, but I have no idea on how to calculate the next byte block (or any subsequent block). This is simplified code, without error handling, but I think it shows clearly how I generate my first bye block.

```
public byte[] GetBytes(int byteCount)
{
    byte[] result = new byte[byteCount];

    byte[] pwd = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_PassPhrase);
    byte[] salt = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_Salt);

    byte[] pwdAndSalt = new byte[pwd.Length + salt.Length];
    pwd.CopyTo(pwdAndSalt, 0);
    salt.CopyTo(pwdAndSalt, pwd.Length);

    byte[] hash = _Sha1.ComputeHash(pwdAndSalt);
    for (int i = 1; i < _Iterations; i++)
    {
        hash = _Sha1.ComputeHash(hash);
    }

    hash.CopyTo(result, 0);

    return result;
}
```

Anyone have an idea how to implement `PasswordDeriveBytes` properly in Silverlight to generate identical keys as the regular .NET version? I would be very grateful.

Thanks